# Type families to check validity rather than satisfiability

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-variables

Consider the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test () where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Void
import GHC.TypeLits

data N = S N | Z
type family Index e l where
  Index e (Either e x) = 'Z
  Index e (Either e' y) = S (Index e y)
  Index e Void = TypeError ('Text " not found")
```

Loading this on GHCi I run the followung

```
λ> :set -XRankNTypes
λ> :kind! forall a . Index a (Either a Void)
forall a . Index a (Either a Void) :: N
= 'Z
λ> :kind! forall a . Index a (Either a (Either Int Void))
forall a . Index a (Either a (Either Int Void)) :: N
= 'Z
λ> :kind! forall a . Index a (Either Int (Either a Void))
forall a . Index a (Either Int (Either a Void)) :: N
= Index a (Either Int (Either a Void))
λ> :kind! Index Char (Either Int (Either Char Void))
Index Char (Either Int (Either Char Void)) :: N
= 'S 'Z
```

Now it is obvious that GHC does not evaluate `Index e (Either Int y) =
S (Index e y)` because `e` might be `Int` so it just stops. Is there a
way to universally quantify `e` so that if `e ~ Int` does not work
forall `e`, then go on? Ideally I would like to get:

```
λ> :kind! forall a . Index a (Either Int (Either Char Void))
forall a . Index a (Either Int (Either Char Void)) :: N
= 'S ('S (TypeError ...))
```

Comment: Can you give more context about why you need this, so we have an idea of what kind of workaround would be acceptable? How about another type family: `type family Elem e l :: Bool`? Then `forall a. (Elem a l ~ False) => ...` would actually quantify over the same types, but it's not clear whether it works for your purposes.

Comment: If you use a skolem type (e.g. `data A`) instead of a type variable, this could work, depending on what you need.  That is, just instantiate the type variable(s) with "fresh" concrete types.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like [`Data.Constraint.Forall`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html) ?

Comment: @chi @li-yao-xia That looks promising but it is not clear how I would be able to write a type function that would `forall a . Index Int (Either a (Either Int (Either Char Void))` evaluate to `S Z`

Comment: @li-yao-xia the question mostly aims at triggering a discussion around the subject. It's something I have encountered one way or another multiple times and I would like to know what people have to say about it. It's not anchored to a particular use case.